# Are there scenic boats to see the ocean floor around Vigo?

Tags: spain, tours, ecotourism

The ocean floor around Rias Baixas is very rich in life. I would like to see it, and I was wondering if there are tours in boats with glass bottom to appreciate all the beauty.

Comment: If you search for rias baixas vision submarino you will get loads of hits (in Spanish) which assuming you can run a translation app should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different tourist boats serving the area"

When I last visited in 2016 there was at least one company with a glass bottomed boat

http://crucerosriasbaixas.com

They have a booking office in Vigo, and on the website you can see a picture of the 'vision submarino' boat.

The website does not seem to have an English version. But is fairly explanatory

Answer (score 0):

The heart of Rias Bajas is actually the ria of Pontevedra. I am quoting the tourist office in Vigo. I was focusing on Vigo ria, which has many boats, but mainly going to Cies.
Around Pontevedra ria there are many cities with boats with glass floor. Unfortunately they focus mostly on the mussel route. It's still very interesting but you shouldn't expect to see much of the ria floor.